# esc_sql inserting weird chars to DB

Tags: wpdb

I am using esc_sql function for making safer SQL operations but i am mysteriously getting `? and &nbsp;` in the DB table how can i avoid them.

Edit : Here is my array after esc_sql()

```
Array
(
    [image_main] => http://market.watchprosite.com/img/watchprosite/market/23/post/market_image.3444923.jpg
    [0] => Rolex  (more) \n\n\n
    [1] => WG Submariner dial (only)
    [2] => 116619
    [3] => MINT
    [4] =>  
    [5] =>  
    [6] =>  
    [7] =>  
    [8] => WTB: Want To Buy
    [9] => Aug 7, 2013, 7:00 AM
    [10] => EUR 1,000&nbsp(in USD)
    [11] => EUR  *(estimate)\n
    [12] =>  
    [description] => Looking for a spare dial from a Rolex Submariner 116619 (white gold). Urgently! Plenty of references available as a good buyer and seller and I expect the same from you. Thanks in advance!!!! Carl
)
```

I am using this function for applying esc_sql for each value.

```
public static function sanitizeInput($key='',$value=''){
        return trim(esc_sql($key));
    }
```

Here is the actual query which is generating :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_scrubed_data SET 

                                    keywords='{"brand":"rolex","model":"","WTB":1,"FS":0}',

                                    url_to_post='http://market.watchprosite.com/?show=collection.detail&id=163938&brandview=Rolex&mod=&series=+WG*+WG+Submariner+dial+%28only%29&p=Rolex+WG*',

                                    description='Looking for a spare dial from a Rolex Submariner 116619 (white gold). Urgently! Plenty of references available as a good buyer and seller and I expect the same from you. Thanks in advance!!!! Carl',

                                    date_captured=now(),crawl_id='6',

                                    image_main='http://market.watchprosite.com/img/watchprosite/market/23/post/market_image.3444923.jpg',

                                    images='["http:\/\/market.watchprosite.com\/img\/watchprosite\/market\/23\/raw\/market_image.3444923.jpg"]',brand='Rolex  (more)',

                                    series='WG Submariner dial (only)',model='116619',

                                    watch_condition='MINT',box=' ',

                                    papers=' ',year=' ',case_size=' ',status='WTB: Want To Buy',listed='Aug 7, 2013, 7:00 AM',

                                    asking_price='EUR 1,000&nbsp(in USD)',retail_price='EUR  *(estimate)',payment_info=' ',forum_id='1'
```

This is working good in phpmyadmin.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure, you already have those _mysterious_ chars **before** you run `esc_sql`. It seem's as if somewhere before you call `esc_html` or `htmlspecialchars` or seomthing like this...

Comment: I double checked my array of data by print_r but this does not have any ? and &nbsp;.

Comment: Did you look at the source of the page? Browsers will interpret encoded characters.

Comment: Yes i checked that too.

Comment: Plz check the edited post with array printed after esc_sql.

Comment: What looks the array (data) like **before** `esc_sql`? And could you also include your code on how you apply the `esc_sql`?

Comment: @t-f Plz check update.

Comment: You are sanitizing the **key**? Sorry, but I can't follow your approach/code... Besides that, I don't see a `?` anywhere. Where do you see one?

Comment: When i print and run the sql in PHPmyadmin this is inserting fine. May be $wpdb->query($qry) is doing something.

Comment: use [`prepare`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) instead of `esc_sql`

Comment: @Milo I switched from  prepare to esc_sql because i was unable to see what going into the sql,if is there is any error in the sql the $wpdb->last_query and $wpdb->last_error was empty.